# ボタンの名前を日本語にしたい(Qt Creator 3.3.1)

Tags: c++, qt5, qt

Qt Creator 3.3.1 でアプリ開発の勉強中です。

以下のコードだとCancelなどのボタンの名前が変えられません。
**Cancel**を**キャンセル**、**Save**を**保存**などの日本語に変えたいのですが、
どのようにすればよろしいでしょうか？

```
 QMessageBox::StandardButton ret;
 ret = QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Application"),
       tr("The document has been modified.\n"
          "この変更をセーブしますか？"),
       QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard | QMessageBox::Cancel);
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

メッセージボックスを表示する前に、日本語の言語ファイルをロードしてください。

```
QTranslator translator;
translator.load("qt_ja_JP", QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath));
qApp->installTranslator(&translator);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
mainwindow.hに以下の追加が必要でしたが、日本語になりました。
#include <QTranslator>
#include <QLibraryInfo>